# Redireccionar multiples requests get en una sola linea o funcion

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

He acabado una web y estoy creando las redirecciones 301 necesarias en el fichero `.htaccess`.

Tengo uno de los sitemaps de la web vieja que tiene 100+ peticiones del tipo:

```
?menu=nombre-del-plato
```

En la nueva web no hay requests similares y todos deben ser redirigidos a, digamos, `http://mirestaurante.com/menu`

Hay alguna manera de evitar estas 100+ lineas iguales en el `.httacces`?:

En vez de:

```
Redirect 301 /?menu=nombre-del-plato1 http://mirestaurante.com/menu
Redirect 301 /?menu=nombre-del-plato2 http://mirestaurante.com/menu
Redirect 301 /?menu=nombre-del-plato3 http://mirestaurante.com/menu
Redirect 301 /?menu=nombre-del-plato4 http://mirestaurante.com/menu
```

Hacer una linea o funcion similar a:

```
Redirect 301 ?menu* http://mirestaurante.com/menu
```

**EDIT:** estas peticiones estan en dos idiomas

```
Redirect 301 /?menu=nombre-del-plato3 http://mirestaurante.com/menu
Redirect 301 /ca/?menu=nombre-del-plato3 http://mirestaurante.com/ca/menu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que todas las URLs que quieres redireccionar tienen una cosa en común: todos son del tipo `?menu=nombre-del-plato`, por lo que en el *query string* está la cadena `?menu=`. Así, lo que podrías hacer es crear una única regla en .htaccess que redireccione si se encuentra esa cadena.

La regla quedaría así:

```
# Si la solicitud incluye un query string con el menú, entonces redirecciona al menú
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} menu=
RewriteRule . http://mirestaurante.com/menu? [L,R=301]
```

Esto redirecciona de forma permanente (por el flag R=301) todas las URLs que contengan `?menu=` en el *query string* a la URL `http://mirestaurante.com/`, eliminando los parámetros de la URL (por el `?` al final de la URL a la que se redirecciona), y es la última regla que se revisa (por el flag L).

---

Ahora, si lo que quieres es que redireccione de manera diferente dependiendo del idioma, lo más sencillo sería tener dos reglas (aunque estoy seguro de que se podrían juntar en una sola):

```
# Si la solicitud incluye un query string con el menú y la cadena /ca/ en la URI
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} menu=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ca/
# Entonces redirecciona al menú en catalán
RewriteRule . http://mirestaurante.com/ca/menu? [L,R=301]

# Si la solicitud incluye un query string con el menú, entonces redirecciona al menú
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} menu=
RewriteRule . http://mirestaurante.com/menu? [L,R=301]
```

Es importante que pongas la regla más específica primero, porque si pones la más genérica antes, entonces nunca se llegará a la segunda regla.

Comment: alvaro, gracias por la respuesta... es también equivalente para multi idioma? he editado la pregunta... gracias!

Comment: En teoría sí. Lo único que se comprueba en la condición es el query string, sin importar cuál sea el resto de la url o de los parámetros

Comment: Sigh, lo que sospechaba, entonces no puedo discriminar cada url añadiendo `{QUERY_STRING} /ca/?menu`, verdad?

Comment: @JordiCastilla Podrías crear dos reglas en lugar de una, sólo serían dos líneas más de código. Deja que mire la edición y actualizo la respuesta

Comment: @JordiCastilla mira ahora. Realmente son dos reglas y no una, seguramente pueda simplificarse con una expresión regular, pero no he dado con la clave

Comment: solucionado, las reglas de wordpress me machacaban las mias, cambiando el orden ha funcionado perfecto! :)